# Saber si cargo mi imagen completamente html

Tags: javascript, html

Hace unos días comencé a hacer una aplicación web para subir imágenes y mostrarlas así como un portafolio web, pero hay un pequeño problema de estética y es que en el post que se sube, hay texto arriba y texto abajo y la imagen queda en medio de los dos. Obviamente algunas imágenes cuestan en cargar de acuerdo a su tamaño y por ende cuando la imagen no carga los textos quedan unidos, algo así:

**Title Post**

**This is my description**

Y cuando la imagen carga correctamente queda algo así:

**Title Post**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**This is my description**

Mi objetivo es que mientras aun no carga la imagen, poner una imagen estática o algún gif que haga referencia que esta cargando la imagen (Algo como un loader), supongo que debo capturar alguna propiedad del DOM que cambia al momento de cargar la imagen, pero desconozco mucho ese tema

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la propiedad onload de la imagen, cuando cargue la imagen ocultar el loader y mostrar la imagen.

https://javascript.info/onload-onerror

```js
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
const imageSrc = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595355728145-2c8d5863ccf0";

async function loadImage(url, elem) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    elem.onload = () => resolve(elem);
    elem.onerror = reject;
    elem.src = url;
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {  
  loadImage(imageSrc, image).then(() => {
    console.log("loaded image");
    loader.style.display = "none";
    imageContainer.style.display = "block";
  })
});
```

```css
img {
  max-height: 400px;
}

#imageContainer {
  display: none;
}

#loader {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>titulo</h1>
  <div id="imageContainer">
    <img id="image" />
  </div>
  <div id="loader">loading image</div>
  <p>descripción</p>
</div>
```

En vez de usar display: none, puedes usar opacity y heigth para hacer una transicion mas bonita.